# Lubridate warning when parsing multiple date formats

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame with a character column that has dates formatted in 2 different ways, one is mm/dd/yy and the other is dd/mm/yyyy, so I wanted to use lubridate to parse them conditioning on the number of characters.

```
x <- c("01/11/24", "17/11/2023", "02/25/24", "01/03/2022")
df <- as_tibble(x)
new_df <- df %>% mutate(value = if_else(nchar(value) == 8, mdy(value), dmy(value)))
```

This seems to produce the correct date column however it generates this warning:

```
 new_df
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  value     
  <date>    
1 2024-01-11
2 2023-11-17
3 2024-02-25
4 2022-03-01

Warning message:
There were 2 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `value = if_else(nchar(value) == 8, mdy(value), dmy(value))`.
Caused by warning:
!  1 failed to parse.
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning. 
> dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()
[[1]]
<warning/rlang_warning>
Warning in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `value = if_else(nchar(value) == 8, mdy(value), dmy(value))`.
Caused by warning:
!  1 failed to parse.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─df %>% ...
 2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
 3. └─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)

[[2]]
<warning/rlang_warning>
Warning in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `value = if_else(nchar(value) == 8, mdy(value), dmy(value))`.
Caused by warning:
!  1 failed to parse.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─df %>% ...
 2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
 3. └─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
```

Not sure what the warning is telling me as it claims 1 failed to parse yet it appears all 4 parsed correctly.

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-if-else-and-getting-warning-because-of-type-error/77319

Comment: Note the the  moment the arguments are passed into the `if_else` function, they are evaluated first. No NSE in the implementation, thus you first evaluate `mdy(x)` and `dmy(x)` and then use the condition to replace. This is not ideal, thus to be error proof, consider using `[`(extraction operator) instead of ifelse/if_else. Note that internally, bothe ifelse/if_else uses `[` operator

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case once and I think what happens is that `if_else()` performs each operation on the entire vector (not just the logical subset) and discards the irrelevant parts only afterwards.

Would be curious to know why this is the case though, especially with regard to performance this behavior does not seem to be beneficial.